# Send udp binary packet - php

Tags: php, binary, udp

I have a problem with sending binary packages by *udp* in php.

My code:

```
$frame[0] = 0x5A;
$frame[1] = 1;
$frame[2] = 1;
$frame[3] = 0;
$frame[4] = $frame[0] ^ $frame[1] ^ $frame[2] ^ $frame[3];

$frame_pack = $frame[0] . $frame[1] . $frame[2] . $frame[3] . $frame[4];

$socket = stream_socket_client($link_syntax);
fwrite($socket, $frame_pack);
stream_socket_sendto($socket, "Out of Band data.", STREAM_OOB);
fclose($socket);

Result var_dump($frame_pack): string(7) "9011090"
```

Send packets to the server - OK. Now I need to send a `$frame_pack` in binary form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$frame_pack = $frame[0] . $frame[1] . $frame[2] . $frame[3] . $frame[4];
```

Replace the following

```
$frame_pack = pack("C*", $frame[0], $frame[1], $frame[2], $frame[3], $frame[4]);
```